# What's python 3.5 strategy of implementing coroutine await by IO multiplexing?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Python 3.5+ supports coroutinne with keyword `await` and IO multiplexing library `asyncio`. I'm connfused about how python3.5+ implement coroutine with IO multiplexing.

For example we have 2 functions:

```
#example-1 

async def f1(x, y):
  for i in range(10):
    r = await x + y
    print(r)

async def f2(x, y):
  for i in range(10):
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    r = await f1(x, y)
    print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import asyncio
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(f2(1, 2))
  loop.close()
```

In `example-1` we have only 1 thread, when function `f1` execute to line `await asyncio.sleep(1.0)`, `f1` will release CPU and sleep for 1 second. function `f2` will get the CPU and continue, when `f2` execute to line `await asyncio.sleep(1.0)` it will also release CPU and sleep for 1 second.

Suppose all of above is correct, I'm confused about how this feature combined with IO multiplexing. In my understanding, IO multiplexing is implemented by system API such as `select`/`epoll`/`kqueue`, but I didn't see any file descriptor combined with `example-1`.

Comment: I think the edited code will just fail with an exception because it awaits a number, which is not awaitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO multiplexing APIs such as `select` and `epoll` support timeouts. `asyncio.sleep` uses `loop.call_later` to ensure the resumption of its awaiter once the timeout elapses. The implementation of `call_later` adds the wakeup time to an ordered list of wakeup times. When the event loop finishes its iteration and goes to sleep, it waits for a coroutine to become runnable, which can happen if:

- something happened on a file descriptor a coroutine has registered interest in, or
- the next wakeup time registered by a coroutine is reached.

So instead of calling `select([fd1, fd2, fd3])`, the event loop calls `select([fd1, fd2, fd3], timeout=next_wakeup_time - now)`. In your case the list of file descriptors would be empty, or would only consist of file descriptors internal to the event loop, and the wakeup time would be 1 second in the future.

Comment: For other expressions such as: `c = await a + b` or `r = await some_func()`, how does python evaluate the next wakeup time?

Comment: @linrongbin Next wakeup time is calculated for the whole event loop, and is simplly the wakeup that comes first chronologically. If `some_func` schedules a wakeup (or awaits something else that schedules a wakeup) and suspends, its wakeup will be added to a sorted list of wakeups. Once that time has been reached, the task will be resumed. See [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) for a live demonstration of how it all comes together. (The lecture uses the older `yield from` syntax instead of `await`, but don't let that throw you off, the mechanism is exactly the same.)

Comment: I have saw the lecture about PyCon 2015, and it's great. But I didn't find anything about how python decide next wakeup time about the `yield` or `await` expressions.

Comment: @linrongbin You're right, his implementation was constrained by lecture time, so it doesn't include sleeping. In his model a `sleep()` coroutine could yield something like `"sleep_until", wakeup_time`, and the event loop would simply specify the time to the soonest wakeup time as timeout.

Comment: Hi, I had update my questions, in the example-1, function `f1` has a line `r = await x + y`, how does python3.5+ decide next wakeup time about this expression ?

Comment: @linrongbin The answer is the same as before: whenever `await`  suspends, the bottom-most coroutine - the one that caused suspension - must tell the event loop when it needs to be resumed (`asyncio.sleep()` does this using `call_later`). The event loop monitors events that lead to resumption, i.e. IO and timeouts, and determines the wakeup time as the time of the nearest timeout. You can take a look at [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0f56263e62ba91d0baae40fb98947a3a98034a73/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1850), but I don't think you'll find a much better explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will read the implementation, thanks for sharing!